# Google Chrome crashes upon entering fullscreen

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, crash, youtube, fullscreen

I'm using the most recent version on a fully-updated system. The crash is caused by both F11 and sometimes simply opening the video in fullscreen (e.g., YouTube).

Comment: There may be a problem with the computer video settings / drivers. Who tells you that the system that you are using is "most recent version" and "fully-updated"? Start by using another program having a similar feature (fullscreen) like Microsoft Power Point, to discard that Chrome causes the problem. Then search Windows Help for crash troubleshooters.

Comment: Wicket's is good advice. Also, trying other browser, specifically, and non-Chrome ones, such as Firefox, in the same way. Update your video drivers.